# Clear Ref in useEffect Cleanup

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I've a hook called useInitial defined as

```
function useInitial(value) {

  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)

  return ref.current;
}
```

I use it in a function component to store an initial value for a field

```
const Calculator = ({ current_field }) => {
  const previousField = usePrevious(current_field);
  const intialContent = useInitial(current_field.content);
  useEffect(() => {
    calculateTotals();
    if (previousField) {
      console.log({ intialContent });
      console.log(previousField.content);
    }
    return () => {
     //DO something here to clear and reset the value stored in intialContent.
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [current_field]);
  return null;
};
```

If the CurrentField changes I want the intialValue for the new field and not the 1st one.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it through and found the solution.

useInitial hook can be modified to have a deps array as inupt like

```
function useInitial(value, deps) {

  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, deps);

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)

  return ref.current;
}
```

And then usage of this could be to send current_field in deps array.

```
const Calculator = ({ current_field }) => {
  const previousField = usePrevious(current_field);
  const intialContent = useInitial(current_field.content);
  useEffect(() => {
    calculateTotals();
    if (previousField) {
      console.log({ intialContent });
      console.log(previousField.content);
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [current_field]);
  return null;
};
```

This will re-trigger the useEffect inside useInitial after field change and new field's initial value will be stored.